# Installing pandas for QPython app on android

Tags: pandas, qpython

I am using the QPython app on my android device to run scripts. I have a script that requires the pandas package but can't seem to download it onto my phone. The app has a section for downloading extra packages under the secion "QPYPI" and then the "AIPY" section. It has numpy and others listed as well as pandas. It starts downloading pandas and gets to the end and says `File is not a zip file`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wOJB.png) is an image of the errors. I was just wandering if anyone knows how to get around this or another way for me to download pandas onto my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what phone, android version, QPython version, where did you install it in advance please ?